# How do we Lorentz transform a derivative?

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry

I want to Lorentz transform a tensor (Einstein tensor) which contains a term $\partial_\sigma \partial_\nu h^\sigma_\nu$. Which makes me wonder how transform the derivative?

Comment: Hint: Why do you write the derivative with a lower single index?

Comment: $\partial_\mu \stackrel{?}{\mapsto} {\Lambda_{\mu}}^\nu \partial_\nu$

Comment: @MariusJonsson Yes. That's why the derivative has an index at the bottom, because it transforms through the inverse Lorentz transformation (inverse with respect to the transformation law for vectors, which are tensors with an index at the top). I guess you're probably confused because $\partial_\mu$ is an operator. But that's okay - just follow the rules for coordinate transformations for upper and lower indices, and it stays valid for all tensors, including $\partial_\mu$.

Comment: Though note that $\partial_\mu$ does not lead to the desired tensor transformation rule, when it acts on nonzero ranked tensors. For that, you use the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$